# How to decode base64 in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, base64

I am working on an API for mobile application, from mobile end I'm getting the image in `base64` format and inserting it in `profile_image` column in my database.

In my web I want to display that image, so how do I decode it:

```
<div class="card horizontal card-driver-details">
    <div class="card-image card-circular">
        <img src="{{ $driver->profile_image}} "> //i want to display here
    </div>
    <div class="card-stacked">
        <div class="card-content">
            <p><b>Name:</b>{{ $driver->first_name }} {{ $driver->last_name }}</p>
            <p><b>Phone:</b>{{ $driver->phone_number }}</p>
            <p><b>Address:</b>{{ $driver->addess_city_village }} {{ $driver->address_state }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: and what have you **tried yourself** so far? perhaps asking [search engine of your choice] for something among the lines of "html img base64"? (related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images )

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
base64_decode($driver->profile_image);
```

Comment: thank you for your time, no response <img src="empty"/>

Answer (score 2):

Try this one.

```
{{ base64_decode($driver->profile_image) }}
```

This will decode the `profile_image` using base 64 and then print the results.

Answer (score 2):

All types of file can be solved by using this ,

```
  $image_64 = $data['photo_url']; //your base64 encoded data

  $extension = explode('/', explode(':', substr($image_64, 0, strpos($image_64, ';')))[1])[1];   // .jpg .png .pdf

  $replace = substr($image_64, 0, strpos($image_64, ',')+1); 

// find substring fro replace here eg: data:image/png;base64,

 $image = str_replace($replace, '', $image_64); 

 $image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image); 

 $imageName = Str::random(10).'.'.$extension;

 Storage::disk('public')->put($imageName, base64_decode($image));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$image = base64_decode('base_64_image_string');
$fp = fopen('path_to_where_you_want_to_save_image','wb+');
fwrite($fp,$image);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: thank you for your time, i'm don't want to store the image just want to decoded and display

Answer (score 0):

i tried with the following code but din't work

```
base64_decode($driver->profile_image);
```

then did some browsing about this then find out now all the updated browser
support `data:image/jpeg/png/gif/etc`

so now i am able to display the image

```
$driver->profile_image
```

Answer (score 0):

To show a base64 converted image in Laravel 10 this works for me.

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ $product->image }}" >
```