# Decode OpenID id_token - JWT

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, jwt

I have an id_token from **OpenID Auth Server**,

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImJlbnVfMTQyNjE1LTEwMDEyMDE3In0.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.NB_Rziv2d5OxDAvs0qQI0m_6Q2DG22DkTKsstNMHiWqFo_LmrmuvsXASnaH3MY7XCwXl0wrTsM5C6rVQiVKmvtIHvAd8TmMfiXIcgnvP-R43wEOXoyATyWEYMw_KWmJkqnanFgEDYpeNeCglO864fLXcjZ9VLpEnerHKtdLjWAL13qhy1kK38UlHeCvAB-sUp62-EBvUfVLj2WCOh011myZZqqc83-HwHk0ddXT74JTm6gCkF0IVal9Ui7ikJ6xlsrp3IR2hNG805D-cIoGf5nk3CDRfO1tGeV1m-bI79wTt_KyOlf3pc30ey0oFdFp0Zo0BurjDebh0LpTUCYi5cQ
```

When I test decode it on :

https://jwt.io/

I got

[image]

I'm wondering, if there a way to achive this decode programatically?

Is there a Laravel framework that will help me achieve that?

I want to be able to get the payload base on my id_token .

Comment: The page you linked has 6 PHP libraries mentioned when you scroll down. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 4):

a JWT consist of 3 parts separated by a dot. The header and the payload are just base64 encoded JSON structures. The solution should be something like this:

```
$jwt_payload = base64_decode('base64_string');
```

Check also this question [How to decode base64 in laravel 5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41690241/how-to-decode-base64-in-laravel-5-3) about how to decode Base64 encoded data in laravel. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend this library: https://github.com/lcobucci/jwt.

You can instantiate `Lcobucci\JWT\Parser` and invoke `parse()` method on token string

```
$parser = \Lcobucci\JWT\Parser();
$parsedToken = $this->parser->parse($token);
```

Then `$parsedToken` will be an object of `Lcobucci\JWT\Token` class on which You can invoke `getClaims()` method to get all information You have inside your token.

Comment: That framework doesn't show us how to use it. :(

Comment: Ok, so basically README says that you can find documentation here: https://github.com/lcobucci/jwt/blob/3.2/README.md you can there code samples which are self-explanatory